# ExtJS 5.1 Build Error (Yui Parse Error)

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd, sencha-cmd5

I use eclipse for ExtJS development,
I am using ant build in eclipse, it uses Sencha cmd.
My project details are

app.framework.version=5.1.0.107

app.cmd.version=5.1.0.26

when I try to build project, it fails with Yui Parse errors, but I couldn't find any error in my workspace..
Can you explain the stack trace message?

```
page:
-before-page:
-init:
-init-compiler:
-copy-app-resources:
[x-compile] Copying page resources to D:\Users\admin\workspaceKepler\Propca\WebContent\build\production\Propca
[x-compile] C2009: YUI Parse Error (missing name after . operator => if (!Propca.view.abstract) Propca.view.abstract = {};) -- unknown-file:143:26
[x-compile] C2009: YUI Parse Error (missing name after . operator =>     Propca.view.abstract,) -- unknown-file:197633:25
[x-compile] C2009: YUI Parse Error (syntax error => ], 0));) -- unknown-file:197635:1
[x-compile] C2009: YUI Parse Error (missing name after . operator =>     Propca.view.abstract,) -- unknown-file:197657:25
[x-compile] C2009: YUI Parse Error (syntax error => ], 0));) -- unknown-file:197659:1
[x-compile] C2009: YUI Parse Error (missing name after . operator => (Ext.cmd.derive('Propca.view.querybuilder.QueryBuilder', Propca.view.abstract.PRPanel, {) -- unknown-file:197661:78
[x-compile] C2009: YUI Parse Error (syntax error =>         items: [) -- unknown-file:197679:15
[x-compile] C2009: YUI Parse Error (missing ; before statement =>                 itemId: 'idbtnValidateSqlScript',) -- unknown-file:197682:24
[x-compile] C2009: YUI Parse Error (syntax error =>                 bodypadding: '30',) -- unknown-file:197683:29
[x-compile] C2009: YUI Parse Error (syntax error =>                 height: 30,) -- unknown-file:197684:24
[x-compile] InvocationTargetException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

BUILD FAILED
com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to compress input
    at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.runYuiCompressor(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:85)
    at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:96)
    at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:106)
    at com.sencha.tools.page.PageModelBuilder.compressAsset(PageModelBuilder.java:413)
    at com.sencha.tools.page.PageModelBuilder.copyResourcesToOutputDirectory(PageModelBuilder.java:398)
    at com.sencha.command.compile.app.AppResourcesCommand.execute(AppResourcesCommand.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
    at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
    at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
    at com.sencha.command.compile.CompileCommands.dispatch(CompileCommands.java:308)
    at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.dispatch(AbstractCommand.java:124)
    at com.sencha.ant.CompileTask$CompileToken.dispatchCommand(CompileTask.java:164)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
Caused by: com.sencha.exceptions.ExReflect: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sencha.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:116)
    at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.runYuiCompressor(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:58)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sencha.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:114)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Compilation produced 379 syntax errors.
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.BaseYuiCompressor$1.invoke(BaseYuiCompressor.java:135)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.runtimeError(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:392)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:337)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:312)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.<init>(JavaScriptCompressor.java:533)
    ... 54 more

Total time: 1 minute 15 seconds
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest it's because you are using a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) in your property name.  While It's typically *"okay"* in javascript and your ExtJS application runs in development mode, I've found when minifying *YUI* chokes on these keywords.

The easiest *(and probably advisable)* option is just to avoid reserved keywords and name **abstract** something else, **abstractObj** for example.  If you wish to force the issue, you could instead of this:

```
if(!Propca.view.abstract) // ...
```

... try array access notation:

```
if(!Propca.view['abstract']) // ...
```

... or in the particular case of the `if` statement in the error message, the `in` operator:

```
if(!('abstract' in Propca.view)) // ...
```

In these cases *(and any others you may have)* accessing the property with the **keyword as a string** seems to satisfy the compiler - though it breaks convention and doesn't look very neat so arguably not worth it...

Comment: Yes, I changed the folder name to prAbstract, and change update all lines in my code which use my abstract classes, than problem fixed. Thank you

Comment: I had almost the exact same issue with a class name of `case`

Answer (score 3):

You've got a syntax error in your JavaScript; when this is combined into a single file, the YUI compressor can't handle it and barfs.

Unfortunately, ExtJS doesn't have good tools for spotting errors in individual files. You could try a different tool (I use jshint, for example, as a pre-build Ant task), or you could simply look at the files that have changed since you last did a successful build and narrow it down that way.